# R bootstrap time series

Tags: r, time-series, random

I would like to generate four bootstrap samples from a time series data set and have each new bootstrapped sample become a new list element.  The sample size needs to be the same length as the original data set.  Can someone please give me a hand?  This is all I could come up with so far.

```
data <- ts(matrix(rnorm(36), 12, 3), start=c(2012, 1), frequency=12)
data
replicate(4, apply(data, 1, sample, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Have a look at the `bootstrap` package.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there. Your description wasn't totally clear at first, but the comment cleared it up. You need to `apply` across columns, and use `list` to make each replicate a list element:

```
boot <- replicate( 4 , list( apply(data , 2 , function(x) sample( x , replace=TRUE ) ) ) )

class(boot)
#[1] "list"

length( boot )
#[1] 4

head(boot[[1]])

#       Series 1    Series 2   Series 3
#[1,]  0.4652513 -0.02065698  0.3328945
#[2,]  0.6649865  0.08845410  0.2032134
#[3,]  0.5975473 -1.64571306  1.6516726
#[4,]  0.5975473 -0.23359075 -0.3255437
#[5,]  0.4008458  0.42180633  1.8402009
#[6,] -0.5436319  1.17034910  0.3456304
```

#### EDIT

Since you need to do whole rows at a time this is even easier!

```
boot <- replicate( 4 , list( data[ sample( nrow(data) , replace = TRUE ) , ] ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But what I would like to end up with is four different data frames, each looking like the original and containing all three Series.  In other words, I would like to build the new data frames by randomly sampling the rows from the original data frame.  If it can be done without converting from ts to data.frame all the better.  Thank you, again.

Comment: @user1491868 OK, I got it now. Sorry, it wasn't clear from your OP. Should be as you wanted now. Cheers.

Comment: @user1491868 Great! Also since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little green check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I jumped the gun a little.  I need to sample one whole row at a time.  Happy to check the green check mark and and upvote too!  Thank you for the help!